# Qm problems rendering in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, rendering, qml

i have the next problem, i finish a app created with qml and c++ (qt 5.3.2, and vs 2010), and works fine, but when i try install in other machine, the gui not works properly, in the next image you can see. (this happens only a one machine, but is possible happen in other machines).

[image: the view of a case for a qml element, not showed correctly]
The text is not showing, and many times after minimize, the window is black. What i can do for  fix this. I try update drivers but have the last drivers, and change the resolution is not solution.

The graphics card is Intel 965, and supports Open GL 2.0(the minimum for Qt Quick).

Answer (score 0):

I can get resolve this issue, in simple way, the elements qml Text and TextInput, have a atribute named renderType, i put for all elements Text as:

```
 renderType: Text.NativeRendering
```

And TextInput as

```
 renderType: TextInput.NativeRendering
```

And with this, the problem is resolved (if you deploy your app for many OS versions, you should use this atribute)